# Moment - get first and last week in a month (the entire week)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to write a simple code, but I'm having an issue with the syntax.

I need to fill up an array with moment.js objects. This array contains all the days that are between 2 dates. This is my logic to achieve this.

- Get monday of the first week of a month (in this case that would be 26/02).
- Get sunday of the last week of a month (in this case that would be (01/04).
- while loop that pushes dates in my array.

Currently this is what I came up with (but it's not working).

```
let start = this.currentDate.startOf("month").startOf("isoWeek");
let end = this.currentDate.endOf("month").endOf("isoWeek");
while (start.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
    this.month.push(start);
    start.add(1, "days");
}
```

this creates crashes my app. When I log my `start` & `end` I see that both days are the same.

`Sun Mar 04 2018 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)`

I assume my syntax is wrong, but I can't fiugre out what.

Answer (score 5):

Both [`startOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`endOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) mutates the original:

> Mutates the original moment by setting it to the start of a unit of time.

you have to use [`clone()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/):

> All moments are mutable. If you want a clone of a moment, you can do so implicitly or explicitly.
>
> Calling `moment()` on a moment will clone it.

Your code could be like the following:

```
let start = this.currentDate.clone().startOf("month").startOf("isoWeek");
let end = this.currentDate.clone().endOf("month").endOf("isoWeek");
while (start.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
    this.month.push(start);
    start.add(1, "days");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this.currentDate.startOf("month") change this.currentDate itself,
so this.currentDate & start & end ref to the same moment object.
because add 1 day to start cause that end add 1 day, 'start.isSameOrBefore(end)' is always true and while(start.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
} 
is in infinite loop

```
    let start = moment(this.currentDate).startOf("month").startOf("isoWeek");
    let end = moment(this.currentDate).endOf("month").endOf("isoWeek");
    while (start.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
         this.month.push(start);
         start.add(1, "days");
    }
```